# How do I prevent dnsmasq from starting on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: dnsmasq

I have an ubuntu 22.04 system I'm running dnsdist on. It's easier to have dnsdist listen on 0.0.0.0, but it can't because dnsmasq it running.
Here's the caveat, the dnsmasq apt package isn't actually installed, so I can't use systemctl to disable it.
Also, the system has no /etc/NetworkManger/NetworkManager.conf, so I can't disable that there.
Must be something in systemd, but...

```
root@thay:/lib# cd systemd/
root@thay:/lib/systemd# find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep -i dnsmasq
root@thay:/lib/systemd#
```

Here's how dnsmasq is running

```
ps ax | grep dnsmasq | grep -v grep
955 ? S 0:00 /usr/sbin/dnsmasq --conf-file=/var/lib/libvirt/dnsmasq/default.conf --leasefile-ro --dhcp-script=/usr/lib/libvirt/libvirt_leaseshelper
956 ? S 0:00 /usr/sbin/dnsmasq --conf-file=/var/lib/libvirt/dnsmasq/default.conf --leasefile-ro --dhcp-script=/usr/lib/libvirt/libvirt_leaseshelper
```

So what is starting this, and how do I disable it?
Here's another weird thing

```
root@thay:/etc/systemd/system# systemctl list-unit-files | grep dnsmasq
dnsmasq.service                            masked          enabled
```

It's masked, and shouldn't even start, which means that some other process is starting this outside of systemd context.

Comment: It seems that I can do
apt remove dnsmasq-base
but there's gotta be a more elegant solution

Comment: It's actually running `systemd-dnsmasq`, which is a different package. Read `man systemd-dnsmasq`.

Comment: Interesting, no man page locally for that or on google.